# How to connect REST api using Meteorjs

Tags: meteor

Actually  I m new in Meteorjs. I dont understand how to connect REST api from Meteor.

Suppose my  REST root url is

```
localhost:1000
```

and request URI is

```
POST /users.json
```

. Parameter are

```
key
```

and

```
id
```

Comment: Using the **REST** api is not coherent with the way **meteor** works. If you need to connect to some existing infrastructure that is not written in **meteor** you should implement a [ddp server](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/livedata/DDP.md) instead. This will require using `WebSockets` so it's probably a little harder than an ordinary **REST server**.

Comment: I just follow Meteor documentation.Here is my code :
`Meteor.http.call("POST", url, { params: { pio_appkey: appkey ,pio_uid: "xa4" }},function(err,result){
        console.log(result);


        if(err) console.log(err);
      }) ; `
But it shows **undefined** !

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499625/how-do-i-setup-an-api-to-access-my-meteor-collection/18505608#18505608) that discusses meteor rest api

Comment: What happens when you use the synchronous version?  Also, try wrapping it in a try..catch.  Is it throwing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't try this package by myself, but I heard it's do that work well http://github.differential.io/reststop2/

Comment: Thanks . But I dont want to make an api , I just want to use an api.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `collections-api` package on Atmosphere. It does exactly what you want:

https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/collection-api

Comment: But it works on only Collection . Not independently.

Comment: E.g in the example they add the `Players` collection in via `collectionApi.addCollection(Players..`